# FlipClock.js on event is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I've an error with FlipClock.js when I try to get event with on method.

My code:

```
var counter = $('.counter').FlipClock(0, {
    clockFace: 'Counter',
    minimumDigits: 3
}).on('set:time', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

I have this on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipClock(...).on is not a function

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Which version of FlipClock you are using?

Comment: I'm using FlickClockJS 0.7.8 - Fiddle paste https://jsfiddle.net/eya18j1m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into your jsfiddle example, I can see that you do not react on the jQuery element.

I have tested your code with following changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var counter = $('.counter').FlipClock(0, {
    clockFace: 'Counter',
    minimumDigits: 3,
    events: true
  });
  counter.$el.on('set:time', function() {
    alert('test event');
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    alert('Set!');
    counter.setTime(10);
  });
});
```

This works perfectly!

In my correction of the, I am listening on the event by the jQuery element.

Please vote and approve the answer.